# LLVM how to link dynamic symbols to executable

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I am currently using the `llvm::sys::DynamicLibrary::AddSymbol` to create and store symbols into the current process. I need to compile the module to an object file. When I use `ld`, it gives me errors stating that this symbols previously added to the dynamic library do not exist. How can I add symbols at runtime and then compile them and link them to the object file?